# Frattini and nilpotency

Tags: lie-algebras

suppose that 
$L$ 
is Lie(Leibniz) Algebra and 
$L^2$ 
is nilpotent.How to show that for any subalgebra 
$M$
of 
$L$, 
$\Phi(M)\subseteq \Phi(L)$?

$\Phi(L)$ is frattini ideal.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

This is proved in E.L. Stitzinger, Frattini subalgebras of a class of solvable Lie algebras, Pacific J. Math. 34 (1970) 177–182.